# Check logs for errors regularly but prevent sending repetitive notifications

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script for checking below-listed `strings[$string]` in my log and send a mail with the relevant logs attachment if one of that pattern matches on that logs.

This script is working as expected, but my challenge is now to check how to exclude already alerted strings. For example:

My log file overwrites every 4 mins or sometime faster than 4 mins which is based on the call traffic. Since my script is running every 3 mins, sometimes I get numerous alert mails for the same error.

So, how to check if that error is new or already alerted before sending a mail to me? I am new to Powershell scripting. Thanks in advance!

Script:

```
$string='(Unable to connect to the remote server|A serious|Socket error - cannot connect|Fetch returned HTTP error|"Open error|URL=http")'
$path1="D:\Program Files\AVP\*.txt"
$Target = "D:\Program Files\AVP\Avp_Logs.zip"

if (Select-String -Path $path1 -pattern $string)
{
    set-alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $count=(Select-String -Path $path1 -pattern $string).length
    $string1=Select-String -Path $path1 -pattern $string
    sz a  $Target $Source -ssw ;
    $body1=("The Error:-"+$string+": "+"Error Count"+" "+$count+"::")
    $string1 | ConvertTo-Html  | Out-File 'E:\PowershellScripts\test.html'
    $body=""
    $body=$body1+$body2
    Send-MailMessage -From "alert@domain.com" -To user@domain.com-Attachments $Target -Subject "A Seriuos Error on server1,please check" $body -BodyAsHtml  -SmtpServer domain.com
}
else
{
    write-host "nothing to process"
}
```

Comment: You must store some kind of state information somewhere, so that when the script starts again it can figure out what it was doing the last time. This requires some knowledge about the log files you are working with. Do they have fixed names and are overwritten (this is also called "log rotation"), or to they have names based on the date, and new lines are only appended until the next day, when a new file is started?

Comment: Hi Tom .. yes that's correct...I have a fixed file name[log1.txt]. once the current log file[log1.txt] reaches to 50MB, it renames to log1.txt.1. I am searching this strings only on log1.txt file....

Comment: Sep 17 14:55:25.89|4668|10|5000||Queuing TTS (application/synthesis+ssml): <?xml version='1.0'?><speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:base="D:\PROGRA~1\ASPECT~1\UNIFIE~1\AVP\config\Defaults.xml" xml:lang="en-US">          A serious error has occured.  Exiting.            </speak>
Sep 17 14:55:25.89|4668|10|8002|com.vocalocity.vxi|VXI::executable_element - 40

Comment: Sep 17 14:55:25.89|4668|10|8002|com.vocalocity.vxi|VXI::var_element(name="vxml_status_code" expr = "0")
Sep 17 14:55:25.89|4668|10|4000|SBjsiCreateVarExpr|entering: 0x0C61DC28, 'vxml_st

Comment: So the log file name is fixed, the file is effectively a CSV file with `|` as the delimiter, and every entry has a date in the first column? If there are multiple log files, do these three assumptions apply to all of them?

Comment: yes, that's correct .. every line writes with data and time... Yes i do have multiple files but i want to look any errors on log1.txt file only as which is the one holds all the current events.

Comment: yes, that's correct .. every line writes with data and time... Yes i do have multiple files but i want to look any errors on log1.txt file only as which is the one holds all the current even